# No defined configuration in QT5 on Ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu

My aim is to execute the simple "Hello World" code in QtCreator5 on Ubuntu (Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS). For this, I've installed QtCreator and its libraries. When I create a Non-qt-projet Plain C++ application and execute it, I obtain the following error :

```
Impossible to deploy : no defined configuration
Error while compilation/deployment of the project (kit : desktop)
When executing step "Send files via SFTP"
```

I verified the used Kit, in the Qt version field, I have: Qt 5.9.5 in PATH(qt5)

Also, when put the fields "peripheral type" to "Desktop" and "Mobile device" to "Local PC", I'm getting this error :

```
In file included from ../wx/main.cpp:1:0:
/usr/include/c++/7/iostream:38:10: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No 
such file or directory
#include <bits/c++config.h>
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:315: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
16:50:39: Le processus "/usr/bin/make" s'est terminé avec le code 2.
Erreur lors de la compilation/déploiement du projet wx (kit : Desktop)
The kit Desktop has configuration issues which might be the root cause 
for this problem.
When executing step "Make"
```

Any ideas ? thank you

Comment: Looks like it's (incompletely) set up to deploy to another (embedded) device

Comment: but i'm using only one laptop. Which device are you talking about ?

Comment: Make sure that in your Kit, you have “Device: Local PC” configured, and not something else.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: After changing the fields "peripheral typpe" and "mobile device" (as you recommand) and after getting the new error : bits/C++config.h No such file or directory, it appears that the problem was related to a crossplatform compilation issue. To reseolve this, I installed the multilib package with "sudo apt install g++-multilib" and it works fine. Thank you